# Angular 2 ViewChild implementation with ES5

Tags: javascript, angular, dom, dependency-injection, es5-shim

I am writing an app for angular 2 with ES5.

I want to have a component with dynamically loaded view child, that will load existing components.

I saw examples in TypeScript but I am failing do that in ES5, and to inject `ng.core.ViewChild` in component constructor based on a `ng.core.Directive` and update the contents of the DOM element ( marked with that directive) with a dynamically loaded, existent, component.

I've tried with

```
queries:[
    formBody: ng.core.ViewChild('formBody')
]
```

...and I get a `ElementRef`, but would need a `ViewContainerRef` to update DOM contents with a dynamically loaded component.

I've tried :

```
queries:[
    formBody: ng.core.ViewChild(app.FormBodyDirective)
]
```

... but I get a "empty" object. `__proto__ object`

Component is loaded like this:

```
ngAfterViewInit: function() {
    var dialogComponentFactory = this.componentResolver.resolveComponentFactory(app.FormBody1_Component);
    this.formBody = this.formBody.createComponent(dialogComponentFactory);
},
```

I have tried to inject `ng.core.ViewContainerRef` into component constructor:

```
.Class({
      constructor: [ 
        ng.core.ViewContainerRef,
        function(viewContainer){
          this.formBody = viewContainer
      }],
```

but this of course injects a instance of `ng.core.ViewContainerRef` for my 'qform' element, and I get the dynamically loaded component at the end of the 'qform' element

Link to plunker with my code (not working) http://plnkr.co/edit/mRxGKYvKy8tHRjupNzju?p=preview

I would be very grateful if someone would help me sort this out, or throw a hint..

Thanks !

Comment: The question is, WHY are you attempting this in ES5?

Comment: The project is written already in ES5, I am trying to add functionality, but apparently without luck.

Answer (score 0):

I finally find a solution. I am not sure that this is the best and most elegant way, but it works.

I injected `ng.core.ViewContainerRef`, in directive constructor and saved it's instance into class member.

The directive class member was accessible from within component. It was made available through component's `queries` option.

The directive:

```
app.FormBodyDirective = 
    ng.core.Directive({
      selector: '[formBody]'
    }).Class({
      constructor: [
        ng.core.ViewContainerRef,
        function(viewContainer){
          this._viewContainer = viewContainer;
      }]
    });
```

The component:

```
//...
queries : {
     formBody: new ng.core.ViewChild(app.FormBodyDirective)
},
directives:[ app.FormBodyDirective ]
//...
```

Working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/ooWhiMqSFDtGNGdW3LMK?p=preview